# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL, Status 405

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to create a servlet which reads data from a HTML form with the class GetTicketInfo and insert the data in to a MySQL database with the class WriteToDatabase.
The problem is that when I have filled out the HTML form and I press the button, Register Ticket, which should start the process of inserting the data in to the database I get this error in my browser **"HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"**. The URL for my index.html, which contains the form, is `http://localhost/IssueHandler/index.html` I use the Apache Tomcat 7.0.34 server

The console doesn't print any errors but two warnings:

```
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CDM' did not find a matching property.
jan 12, 2015 5:42:06 EM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:IssueHandler' did not find a matching property.
jan 12, 2015 5:42:07 EM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the form not being able to find the servlet, but I have honestly no idea. I've tried adding the servlet-mapping tags and such to the web.xml file but it didn't help.

**GetTicketInfo**

```
package com.issue.handler;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/issueHandler")
public class GetTicketInfo extends HttpServlet {


    String ticketID1, ticketOwner1, ticketTitle1, ticketHandler1, ticketCategory1, ticketDescription1, ticketDate1;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String tID) {
        tID=request.getParameter("ticketID");
        ticketID1=tID;

    }

    public String getTicketID(){

        return ticketID1;

    }


    public void setTicketOwner(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String tOW) {
        tOW=request.getParameter("ticketOwner");
        ticketOwner1 = tOW;

    }

    public String getTicketOwner(){

        return ticketOwner1;

    }

    public void setTicketTitle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String tTI) {
        tTI=request.getParameter("ticketTitle");
        ticketTitle1 = tTI;

    }

    public String getTicketTitle(){

        return ticketTitle1;

    }

    public void setTicketHandler(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String tHA) {
        tHA=request.getParameter("ticketHandler");

        ticketHandler1 = tHA;

    }

    public String getTicketHandler(){

        return ticketHandler1;

    }

    public void setTicketCategory(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String tCA) {
        tCA=request.getParameter("ticketCategory");

        ticketCategory1 = tCA;

    }

    public String getTicketCategory(){

        return ticketCategory1;

    }

    public void setTicketDescription(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String tDE) {
        tDE=request.getParameter("ticketDescription");

        ticketDescription1 = tDE;

    }

    public String getTicketDescription(){

        return ticketDescription1;

    }

    public void setTicketDate(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String tDA) {
        tDA=request.getParameter("ticketDate");

        ticketDate1 = tDA;

    }

    public String getTicketDate(){

        return ticketDate1;

    }



}//GetTicketInfo
```

**WriteToDatabase**

```
package com.issue.handler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class WriteToDatabase {



    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {


        GetTicketInfo myGetTicketInfo = new GetTicketInfo();






        try(    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/school_server";
            String uName = "testuser";
            String uPass = "testuser";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);



            String query = "INSERT INTO issues (ticketID, ticketOwner, ticketTitle, ticketHandler, ticketCategory, ticketDescription, ticketDate)"+ "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement (query);


            preparedStmt.setString(1,myGetTicketInfo.getTicketID());
            preparedStmt.setString(2,myGetTicketInfo.getTicketOwner());
            preparedStmt.setString(3,myGetTicketInfo.getTicketTitle());
            preparedStmt.setString(4,myGetTicketInfo.getTicketHandler());
            preparedStmt.setString(5,myGetTicketInfo.getTicketCategory());  
            preparedStmt.setString(6,myGetTicketInfo.getTicketDescription());
            preparedStmt.setString(7,myGetTicketInfo.getTicketDescription());

            preparedStmt.execute();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception!");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());}



    } 


}
```

**index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Issue Handler</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Issue Handler</h1>

<FORM ACTION="issueHandler" method="get">
  Ticket ID:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ticketID" VALUE=""><BR>

  Ticket Owner:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ticketOwner" VALUE=""><BR>

  Ticket Title:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ticketTitle" VALUE=""><BR>

  Ticket Handler:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ticketHandler" VALUE=""><BR>

  Ticket Category:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ticketCategory" VALUE=""><BR>

  Ticket Description:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ticketDescription" VALUE=""><BR>

  Ticket Date:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ticketDate" VALUE=""><BR>



    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Register Ticket">
</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
  <display-name>Issue Handler</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

Comment: To send form data to server you should use POST.

Comment: updated according to your comment. No difference regarding my error though.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided an override of [`HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29). That's the method the Servlet container uses.

You've provided

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, String tID) {
    tID=request.getParameter("ticketID");
    ticketID1=tID;

}
```

which is a completely unrelated method.

Hint: Annotate the methods you think you're overriding with `@Override`.

Comment: I feel a bit out of my depth here, I get this error in the code if I add the @Override annotation. "The method doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, String) of type GetTicketInfo must override or implement a supertype method"

Comment: @bork Exactly. That method is not overriding anything. You use `@Override` to make sure that's what you're doing. The `doGet` method you've provided is unrelated to any parent class method. You need to override the parent class `doGet` method which has the signature I've linked to.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now overriding the method and I still get the same error in my browser as before.

Comment: @bork Please edit your question with the updated code.